# Can not disable checkbox by value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Here is my code but it is not working.Checkboxes created dynamically.i want to disable checkboxes which their values are "undefined"

```
var val = "undefined";
$('#dynamiccapability').on('input:checkbox[value="' + val + '"]').attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It says undefined when value is empty,try this:

```
$('input:checkbox[value=""]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

1. Use [**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/). The [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements.
2. Use [**.prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), its preferred way

Change you code as

```
$('#dynamiccapability').find('input:checkbox[value=""]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event `.on('input:checkbox`, you need to use change:

```
var val = "undefined";
$(document).on('change','input:checkbox[value="'+val+'"]',function(){
   $(this).prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Or simply use as selector does:

```
$('#dynamiccapability input:checkbox[value="'+val+'"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: all checkboxes are disabled not undefined ones

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var val = "undefined";
$('input:checkbox[value=' + val + ']').attr('disabled', true);
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/gXJB6/)**

Comment: it is a dynamic checkbox so without on it is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dynamiccapability').find('input:checkbox[value=""]').attr('disabled', true);
```